# Latitude isn't accurately but Long is accurately - Android device

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, gps

I try to get my LatLong from android device with GPS.

There is my code :

```
    LocationManager lm,locationManager;
    Location l;
    TextView lt, ln;
    lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        l=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        updateWithNewLocation(l);

         private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
                String latLongString = "Unknown";
                String addressString = "No address found";
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
                if (location != null) {
                    double lat = location.getLatitude();
                    double lng = location.getLongitude();
                    latLongString = "Lat:" +  df.format(lat) + "\nLong:" +  df.format(lng);
                    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses  = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                        if (addresses.size() == 1) {
                            addressString="";
                            Address address = addresses.get(0);
                            addressString = addressString + address.getAddressLine(0) + "\n";
                            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                                addressString = addressString + address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                            }
                            addressString = addressString + address.getLocality()+ "\n";
                            addressString = addressString + address.getPostalCode()+ "\n";
                            addressString = addressString + address.getCountryName()+ "\n";
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        Log.e("Geocoder IOException exception: ", ioe.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                accurity.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString + "\n" + addressString);
                ln.setText(""+lng);
                lt.setText(""+lat);
            }

}
```

I am sending my lat,long to c# code map (Dynamic data display) and draw the point on the map.
The lat is wrong by the code (It close to my location but not accurately.
**Although** from the addressString I got the accurately my address of building and city and country. 
The addressString get from the gps and the Lat long gets from the GPS so why it accurately too?

```
addresses  = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

**Im repit, only the lat is wrong, the long is perfect.**
I would be so thankfull to the one will find the answer of this it really important for me. Thanks.

Comment: LocationManager, especially using GPS provider only, need pretty long time to get highly accurate (lat,lng) pair. You can check the accuracy (location.getAccuracy()) and wait until its small enough. The Fused location provider, which combines GPS, WiFi, Cell, ??? (Google won't tell) is much faster and battery efficient. Take a look!

Comment: Thanks Ken, but what can i do to improve my resualt ? See my edit. the long is prefect, but lat isn't ..

Answer (score 0):

lm.getlastlocation does not always give the exact updated lat long. u need to use a location request object in requestlocationupdate( locationrequest, location_listener) and use the lat long provided the location listener instead, this provides accurate result. Sharing the code below:

```
private LocationRequest mlocationrequest;


// location listener
LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
    {

        if (arg0 != null)
        {
            lat = arg0.getLatitude();
            lng = arg0.getLongitude();
            tm = arg0.getTime();
        }

    }
};
```

And in your on create method

```
mlocationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mlocationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mlocationrequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mlocationrequest.setInterval(10000);
```

Then simple pass

```
 mlocationclient.requestLocationUpdates(mlocationrequest, loc_listener);
```

Comment: what is that locationRequest ? It doesnt exist in eclipse .. It doesnt gives any Import for it..

Comment: u need to use updated location api from google, its available on developer.android.com, the new api integrates itself with google play services

Comment: Study this first: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: Would you help me please ? Where to download it ? What to do with it ? I really doesnt understand

Comment: pls study this  https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html
then u will understand what i wrote in my answer, google has given complete guide to integrate the apis

Comment: Thats what I have been found 
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: In your SDK you can find  subfolder "extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib" which you need to setup in ADT and add it to the library path of your APP. Then the answer above shows you how to write a LocationListener, create LocationRequest and register your listener to it.

Comment: Ok now I got it, I'm downloading the folder now in the SDK. I have question with your permission, Why the address that I got from the location, and the Longitude is perfect and the latitude isn't accurately ?

Comment: Im tried it, doesn't works.. It error "Source not found."
after the line  **mlocationclient.requestLocationUpdates(mlocationrequest, loc_listener);** ............... I did all that need.. Install the package google service, after I'm import it as package in my project, after this im put the manifast (as the SetUp says), and then im did all what you type.. No error in code, just in running it kick me.
**activitythread.performlaunchactivity(activitythread$activityclientrecord intent) line 2293**

Comment: u need to study the  tutorial correctly, everything is there in it.. its very direct and clear...